# Make button within class visible (in multiple instances) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, button, instantiation

```
Public Class Node
Inherits Button
Public weight As Double
Public node As New Button With {
        .Height = 1080,
        .Width = 1800,
        .Left = 1,
        .Top = 1}
End Class
```

make the button visible? sorry if it is a silly question but I just do not understand how to make it so a new Node would present as a button?

Comment: If it inherits `Button` there is already a `Visible` property, so not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Node is just the name of the Class (confusing I know, call it X), but I just want it so that a new button will appear when I dim a "New X"...

Comment: when I write visible = true it does not show

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but that is a Button that contains a Button.  If the inner button props can change (somehow), as is they wont get saved by the designer.  Maybe a UserControl would be a better place to start, hard to say.  It is not showing up because with *that code* you never add it to any Controls collection so it has no parent

Comment: @CameronArmstrong try adding a constructor to the Node class, like this:     `Public Sub New()`
        `Me.Controls.Add(node)`
    `End Sub`

Comment: `I just want it so that a new button will appear when I dim a "New X"` - It does not work that way.  You need to add your `New X` ( to the `Controls` collection a currently visible control (the main Form  or one of its child controls),

Comment: A control is a control.  Yours is no different to any other.  You add one to a form in exactly the same way as you do any other control, so it will be easy to find out how to do so by searching the web.

Comment: @djv thanks that's what it is, terribly explained I know (soz)